# kendo-datetimepicker: how to set min/max

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

How can I set the min/max after the datetimepicker has been created?

With the datepicker I can do something like this:

```
var start = $("#start").kendoDatePicker();
start.max(endDate);
```

However, the datetimepicker won't allow that.

I get the error as

> "Uncaught TypeError: start.max is not a function"

Answer (score 3):

Do it like kendo doc [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#methods-max) does, just like this i limit min to yesterday and max to tomorrow :

```
var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");

var $today = new Date();
var $yesterday = new Date($today);
$yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 1);
var $tomorrow = new Date($today);
$tomorrow.setDate($today.getDate() + 1);

var min = datepicker.min($yesterday);
var max = datepicker.max($tomorrow);
```

Here is the [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/awovU) as working example

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used this to deduce the cause: The .data("kendoDateTimePicker") is required as in:

     var start = $("#start").kendoDatePicker().data("kendoDateTimePicker");

     start.max(endDate);